# Door seal to stop spreading cooking odour

Tags: kitchens, sealant

Have reasonably good ventilation and smoke extractor in the kitchen. But still, food/cooking odour are spreading in adjacent rooms; possibly through a small gap between door and frame.

Can anyone suggest me any possible solutions to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Why don't you just seal that gap?

Comment: Doesn't your home's HVAC system move air all over anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd essentially use the type of weather stripping commonly seen on exterior doors. Foam tape, rubber bead gaskets, brass compression strips, bottom sweeps, etc. Which you use is up to you.

I think you'll end up disappointed, though. If odor is escaping even with your exhaust fan running and creating negative pressure, something is moving it around. Sealing that door probably won't yield satisfactory results.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I guess weather stripping would be a point to start though I am not sure on which one yet. But let me start with that before I go back to the builder on this. Much appreciated.